# Error in running the code when changing the environment from Python Environment to Anaconda Environment

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conv-neural-network

I tested this code on "Python Environment" with no error https://github.com/spmallick/learnopencv/blob/master/KerasCNN-CIFAR/keras-cnn-cifar10.ipynb, but when I tried to test the same code on "Anaconda Spyder", I have received this error:

```
Error:

plt.plot(history.history['accuracy'],'r',linewidth=3.0)

KeyError: 'accuracy'
```

I don't understand why the code didn't work when it run it on "Anaconda Spyder" while it works when i run the same code on "Python Environment?". I made many tried to fix this error . I would be happy if you can help me to fix this error.

Comment: what version of python are you running?

Comment: I  am running python 3.8

Comment: did you create a virtual environment for python=3.8?  if yes did you activate it when loading Spyder?

Comment: I installed Python 3.8 from Python Organization site on my device. 

At the beginning, I activated python Environment 3.8 and Anaconda Environment at the same time and test the code on both environments. I thought that I got this error because both environments (python environment and Anaconda Environment) are both activated at the same time so I closed python version 3.8 and run the code again on Anaconda version, but I have received the same error.

Comment: if you go to a terminal window and type a command, then look at your cursor, the first characters in your cursor line will be the name of your activated environment.

Comment: Try activating the environment for python 3.8 only and see if it runs.

Comment: It is run using Python 3.8, but it didn't run using Anaconda Spyder. My question is why the code is run using python 3.8, but it didn't run using Anaconda Spyer?

Comment: which version of Spyder are you running?

Comment: For the name of the activated environment, do you mean this "Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 23:03:10)"?

Comment: I run Anaconda Spyder (Python 3.7)

Comment: what computer are you using?

Comment: I am using HP-laptop (windows 10)